# Can we embed a React app inside another React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, embed

I have a React app called 'Parent', and another React app called 'Child'. Both are created from CRA. Let us say I can access Parent app using http://localhost:3000 and child app using http://localhost:4000. Can I embed the Child app inside Parent?

My assumption - If Child app can be exposed as a dependency(like npm), I can import and use it. Is this a correct way?

Are there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an iframe html tag and giving the link to your other site localhost:4000

Comment: Yes! That would work. But is there any other way? Because I will have to maintain session, pass values as props and receive it back. I don't think iframe solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

use web components instead try [sencil](https://stenciljs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webpack Module federation to achieve this.
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/
Your parent will be the host app, and child can be the remote app

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29836487)

Answer (score -1):

You can most likely just import the other components by using `npm link` in the source code without hosting the apps.

Since they're just react components. Beware, you're bundle size may be a tad larger.

```
# in child repo
npm link
```

```
# in parent repo
npm link <package-name>
```

In your `parent` apps's code, just import it in the file of wherever it needs to go.

```
import App from 'my-child-ui-package'
```

You might need to create an exports file in your Child, where you export all of the components you need.

If you need this in CI/CD, then you can actually publish your child react app to `npm`. Consider making an account, and making it a part of a private registry.